# Calibrate OpenGL projection matrix and hardware camera field of view?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera

I'm trying to calibrate an OpenGL scene onto a preview camera for an augmented reality app, but the defined OpenGL perspective and the camera preview don't seem to match.
While looking around my field of view is obviously too large (in both vertical/horizontal direction).

**Q:** Did I misunderstand the idea of calibrating both?

**Edit:** I did the following check and just can't explain the result to myself.
Using the `trueVerticalFOV` from below for my projection matrix, the camera preview and OpenGL match perfectly.

It seems `getVerticalViewAngle()` didn't return the correct value. I've measured the FOV physically also resulting in `trueVerticalFOV`.

**New Question:** Why is this so? Any suggestions?

Cam Preview size and GLSurfaceView are also 800x480, cam zoom is zero.

```
float horizontalFOV =
    camera.getParameters().getHorizontalViewAngle();    // = 60.5
float verticalFOV =
    camera.getParameters().getVerticalViewAngle();      // = 47.1
float camAspect = hFOV / vFOV;                          // = 1.2845...

float displayWidth =
    getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;     // = 800
float displayHeight =
    getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;    // = 480
float displayAspect = displayWidth / displayHeight;     // = 1.666...

float trueVerticalFOV = horizontalFOV / displayAspect;  // = 36.30...
```

**/Edit**

Device's camera vertical FOV:

```
projectionFieldOfView = camera.getParameters().getVerticalViewAngle();
```

GLSurfaceView's aspect ratio:

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
    ...
    projectionAspect = (float) width / (float) height;
    ...
}
```

OpenGL's projection matrix:

```
Matrix.perspectiveM(
    projectionMatrix,           // projection matrix array
    0,                          // array offset
    projectionFieldOfView,      // FOV [deg]            = 47.1 deg
    projectionAspect,           // aspect ratio         = 1.667
    projectionNearClipping,     // Near clipping plane  = 1
    projectionFarClipping );    // Far clipping plane   = 3000
```

Comment: Does the preview surface's aspect ratio match the camera's?

Comment: Yes, both are w*h 800*480 px. Though the aspect ratio should only affect the horizontal field of view.

Comment: Well, actually just the camera's preview ratio is the same (understandably, both use the whole screen). I'll need to check the camera's aspect. Maybe this differs, messing up the FOV angle...